# Dynamic add divs to html using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add html `divs( with textfields)` using button click.My form look like this :
[image]
On `add size` button click it add one row (`Price` and `size` ) and `one add More item`  button click i want to add new area with `name`,`price` and `size` and so on.
HTML Code is :

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="moreitems form-group" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:200px;display:none;">

                     </div>
```

My js code is :

```
jQuery("#addmoreitems").click(function () {
    var options = jQuery("#select1").html();

jQuery('.moreitems').css("display","block");
    var fld = '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="" class="text-left control-label">Product Name :</label></div><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="required-entry form-control" name="pname[]" id="pname"></div></div></div>';
   fld += '<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="" class="text-left control-label">Price :</label></div><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="required-entry form-control" name="more_prices[]" id="prices"><select name="more_size[]" class="mysize">'+options+'</select></div></div>';
   fld += '<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top:15px;"><button type="button" id="addsize" class="btn btn-info">Add Size</button></div></div>';
jQuery('.moreitems').html(fld);
jQuery('.mysize').html(options);


    });
});
```

But this code add first time.I want to add as many times the add more items button.Also on add more size button want to add price and size fields.

Comment: Could you please create Demo of your HTML code, i have solution but it would be more easy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `html()` function which replaces the entire html contents, where in your situation you want to `append()` the HTML every time you click the button.

Change:

```
 jQuery('.moreitems').html(fld);
```

To:

```
 jQuery('.moreitems').append(fld);
```

Comment: thanks for your message but how the add size on new works ? your append code works but can you help little more for add more size click

Answer (score 0):

Hi as i know the may the problem is in appending the  using the .html() method.

here the difference between this two methods reference link given

http://www.slideshare.net/umarali1981/jqueryappend-vs-jqueryhtml

cause .html() overwrites the contents of the DIV. while .append() will add to the contents of the DIV. so use this and another thing to notify is that you should bind the 'click' event in-spite of using the only 'click' method like.

```js
$("#addmoreitems").unbind('click').bind('click',function () {
    
      // write your code here

});
```